# Get the text from the EditTxt several times

Tags: java, android

assistant Android
I have some problems writing the code
I try to get texts from the EditTexT two times without having to repeat the `if` `else`

Example :
When the user writes `I'm hungry`
It is answered with the word `what do you want to eat`
The user writes the word again by means of an idetict: `hamburger`

It will be as follows for me:

```
public class assisstant extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText replaya;
    private TextView mview;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_new__panda);


        replaya = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.massage);
        mview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pp);

    }


    public void replay (){

        String massage = replaya.getText().toString().trim();


        String[] massage_TO_Split = massage.split(" ");
        String line;
        StringBuilder replay = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < massage_TO_Split.length; i++) {

            line = massage_TO_Split[i];
            replay.append(line.trim());
        }

        String re = replay.toString();

        if (re.contains("hungry")) {

            mview.setText("What do you want to eat ?");
                    if (re.contains("Hamburger")){

                        mview.setText("Would you like me to order you a meal?");
                    }
        }

    }


}
```

XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Test_new_Panda">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Message_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/user_Message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="199dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Send_Message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="210dp"
        android:text="send" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem here is that I can not get to `if/else` again.
When you click the send button, the first operation is repeated only, the first condition is achieved, so I can not complete it to the second condition under the first condition

Answer (score 0):

There's chunks of your code missing, I can't see where you're calling *replay()* from nor any onClickListener set.

Because you have an if statement inside your other if statement the second if can only execute if the first is true.

Also you're using *contains()* which would mean if the user wrote "hungry Hamburger" you'd skip straight to "would you like me to order a meal?".

If you're trying for a natural response algorithm you'd best look at dedicated frameworks, but just for this example I'd define two distinct onClickListeners and go from there.

```
public class OnCommandDetectListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if( replaya.getText().toString().contains("hungry") ) {
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnFoodDetectListener());
            mview.setText("What do you want to eat ?");
            replaya.setText("");// This empties the EditText
        }
    }
}

public class OnFoodDetectListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if( replaya.getText().toString().contains("Hamburger") )
            mview.setText("Would you like me to order you a meal?");
    }
}
```

Remember to add this to your onCreate:

```
button = findViewById(R.id.Send_Message);
button.setOnClickListener( new OnCommandDetectListener() );
```

Hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: Will this technique weaken memory?
Because I will write it more than a thousand times

Comment: This was just to show an example, like I said, if you're going for a natural language parser this is not the way to go about it. You'd need to keep context to understand what the user is talking about. You could try looking at the Google Assistant APIs and hook into that.

Comment: Should I use Google Assistant APIs exclusively for such programs?

Comment: Also I can not use the Arabic language and I want to add it to my application

Comment: Not exclusively but it's bound to be one of the best ones integrated with Android.